# How to select column and rows in pandas without column or row names?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe(df) like this

```
                         Close      Close     Close Close       Close
Date                                                                 
2000-01-03 00:00:00        NaN        NaN       NaN   NaN   -0.033944
2000-01-04 00:00:00        NaN        NaN       NaN   NaN   0.0351366
2000-01-05 00:00:00  -0.033944        NaN       NaN   NaN  -0.0172414
2000-01-06 00:00:00  0.0351366  -0.033944       NaN   NaN -0.00438596
2000-01-07 00:00:00 -0.0172414  0.0351366 -0.033944   NaN   0.0396476
```

in `R` If I want to select fifth column

```
five=df[,5]
```

and without 5th column

```
rest=df[,-5]
```

How can I do similar operations with pandas dataframe

I tried this in pandas

```
five=df.ix[,5]
```

but its giving this error

```
 File "", line 1
    df.ix[,5]
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the fifth column:

```
df.ix[:,4]
```

Stick the colon in there to take all the rows for that column.

To exclude a fifth column you could try:

```
df.ix[:, (x for x in range(0, len(df.columns)) if x != 4)]
```

Comment: its showing this error `IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5` but `df.ix[:,4]` working

Comment: Sorry it is zero-based, so you want 4

Comment: Ok got it . in python its start from 0 and in R it starts from 1

Comment: As for exclusion you can use standard Python language features to create ranges, etc, in your slicing/indexing - I've added an example.

Comment: Usage of `.ix` has been abandoned: use `.iloc` instead.

Answer (score 18):

Use `iloc`.  It is explicitly a position based indexer.  `ix` can be both and will get confused if an index is integer based.

```
df.iloc[:, [4]]
```

[image]

For all but the fifth column

```
slc = list(range(df.shape[1]))
slc.remove(4)

df.iloc[:, slc]
```

[image]

or equivalently

```
df.iloc[:, [i for i in range(df.shape[1]) if i != 4]]
```

Answer (score 3):

If your DataFrame does not have column/row labels and you want to select some specific columns then you should use [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) method.

example if you want to select first column and all rows:

```
df = dataset.iloc[:,0]
```

Here the df variable will contain the value stored in the first column of your dataframe.

Do remember that

```
type(df) -> pandas.core.series.Series
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

To select filter column by index:

```
In [19]: df
Out[19]: 
                 Date     Close   Close.1   Close.2  Close.3   Close.4
0  2000-01-0300:00:00       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN -0.033944
1  2000-01-0400:00:00       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN  0.035137
2  2000-01-0500:00:00 -0.033944       NaN       NaN      NaN -0.017241
3  2000-01-0600:00:00  0.035137 -0.033944       NaN      NaN -0.004386
4  2000-01-0700:00:00 -0.017241  0.035137 -0.033944      NaN  0.039648

In [20]: df.ix[:, 5]
Out[20]: 
0   -0.033944
1    0.035137
2   -0.017241
3   -0.004386
4    0.039648
Name: Close.4, dtype: float64

In [21]: df.icol(5)
/usr/bin/ipython:1: FutureWarning: icol(i) is deprecated. Please use .iloc[:,i]
  #!/usr/bin/python2
Out[21]: 
0   -0.033944
1    0.035137
2   -0.017241
3   -0.004386
4    0.039648
Name: Close.4, dtype: float64

In [22]: df.iloc[:, 5]
Out[22]: 
0   -0.033944
1    0.035137
2   -0.017241
3   -0.004386
4    0.039648
Name: Close.4, dtype: float64
```

To select all columns except index:

```
In [29]: df[[df.columns[i] for i in range(len(df.columns)) if i != 5]]
Out[29]: 
                 Date     Close   Close.1   Close.2  Close.3
0  2000-01-0300:00:00       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN
1  2000-01-0400:00:00       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN
2  2000-01-0500:00:00 -0.033944       NaN       NaN      NaN
3  2000-01-0600:00:00  0.035137 -0.033944       NaN      NaN
4  2000-01-0700:00:00 -0.017241  0.035137 -0.033944      NaN
```